# postgresql join this table on (this, if not null or that)

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I've been going crazy about this for a while, and I'm sure it's simpler that I am currently making it, but couln't find the answer, probably because i can't put the finger on the right question.

I'll explain with an simple example:
Let's say I have 3 tables

fathers:

```
| id  | name |
```

sons:

```
| id |father_id  | name |
```

books:

```
| id  | son_id | father_id |name |
```

I want a query that would give me:

```
[father] | [son] | [book]

---------   ----   -----

father1| son1 | book1

father1 |son1 | book5

father1,son2,book2

father1,none,book3

father1,none,book4

father2...
```

I have:

```
select fathers.name,sons.name,books.name 
from fathers left join sons on son.father_id=fathers.id 
left join books on ...
```

Appreciate any help here!

Update:

It seems when a book is assigned to a son, it is also assigned to the father.

here is my current query:

```
select fathers.name,sons.name,books.name 
from 
    fathers 
    left join sons on son.father_id=fathers.id 
    left join books on (
        (books.father_id=fathers.id and books.son_id is null) 
        or ((books.son_id=sons.id )
    ) 
group by fathers.name,sons.name,books.name
```

But this doesn't get me the conditional "none" on the son column.

Comment: Please post your entire query.

Comment: Strange data model. Put all people in the same table, have a self-referencing fk.

Comment: Can't do much about the data model, it's a given database whose records I'm working with.

Comment: I also found out that when a book is assigned to a son, it's also assigned to the father... so. Here's my current query:    `select fathers.name,sons.name,books.name from fathers left join sons on son.father_id=fathers.id left join books on ((books.father_id=fathers.id and books.son_id is null) or ((books.son_id=sons.id )) group by fathers.name,sons.name,books.name   `    . Problem with this is results are not consistent with what is expected.

Answer (score 1):

Your *son* table already has a relation with *father* table so the *father_id* field in *book* table is extra and redundant if books are only for son and not for fathers.! Otherwise if fathers and sons both can have books then you have to `left join` *book* table with both *father* and *son* table; I mean the query you want is something like below:

```
select f.name, s.name, b.name 
from  Books b left join fathers f on b.father_id=f.id
      left join sons s on b.son_id=s.id
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried that, but didn't work as expected becouse it seems when a book is assigned to the son it also assigns to the father. I posted my current query above.

Comment: Then you shouldn't join books to both table. join 'books to son' and 'sons to fathers'